# Error installing composer on Yosemite

Tags: composer-php

Running `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` gives me the following error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/apache2/users/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Not sure what permissions need to be changed to get this to work. I'm new to Mac OS. I've tried running the same command using sudo but to no avail. Any ideas on what needs to be changed in the apache2 directory to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

A simple chmod 777 on the users folder fixed the issue. Damn I feel like an idiot sometimes.